# Can you use a for loop inside a case_when statement in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, case-when

I'm trying to write a function in R that aggregates data grouped by N price-buckets, where N is an input variable for the function.

```
priceDiffBucket <- function(prices,numBuckets){
  vec <- c(0:numBuckets)
#Create N (numBuckets) buckets where the min/max are rounded off to the lowest/highest 5th integer
  bucketborders <- quantile(c((min(prices)-min(prices)%%5):
                                (max(prices) - max(prices)%%5+5)),probs = vec/numBuckets)
#Create a dataframe which contains these buckets as a column
  dfFinal <- case_when(
    for (i in 1:(length(vec)-1)){
      prices < bucketborders[i+1] ~ paste(paste0('"',bucketborders[i]),"-",
                                          paste0('"',bucketborders[i+1],'"'))
    }
  )
  return(dfFinal)
}
```

After this I would aggregate values based on these buckets. However R doesn't seem to accept for statements in case_when() statements, thus I can't achieve these buckets in a general function. I get the following error:

```
 Error: No cases provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Running Rlang::lst_error() just reveals the last block of code, but doesn't help me. If a for-loop inside a case-when statement is not possible, is what I'm trying to do possible in another way in R?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will do for my next question, seeing my problem currently is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully interpret what you are trying to do.  But the `cut` function is a way to generate "buckets" E.g.:

```
x <- sample(1:100)
breaks <- c(-Inf, 25, 50, Inf)
labels <- c('lo', 'med', 'high')
buckets <- cut(x, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
```

You could then `cbind` your `buckets` vector to your `prices` vector or data frame.

Comment: Thank you! I wished I had known this function earlier, where did the last two hours of my life go? XD

Comment: Great.  Could you upvote the answer and label as answered?  Thanks.